# Should I use CodeIgniter's Unit Testing Class or PHPUnit/TOAST?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, codeigniter

I'm looking for a good unit testing for my web development. I'm using CodeIgniter for PHP, and I found [this class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/unit_testing.html) on CodeIgniter's documentation, so here is my doubt:

**Should I use 'Unit Testing Class' to test my code, or is going to be better to use [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/) or [TOAST](http://jensroland.com/projects/toast/)? Which is better and why?**

I hope someone experienced can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Like it says in the description: "CodeIgniter's Unit Test class is quite simple, consisting of an evaluation function and two result functions. It's not intended to be a full-blown test suite but rather a simple mechanism to evaluate your code to determine if it is producing the correct data type and result. "

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, I think it's better to use the standard **PHPUnit** for unit-testing.

Aside from that it has many nice features, your tests will be more consistent and it wont depend on CakePHP's unit testing class.


If in the future you decide that **CakePHP** does not suite your needs, you'll lose your unit tests. (or lets say, you'll have to migrate them, which is time)

If you are testing code, that depends on CakePHP(Controller, Model, etc), there's no problem to use CakePHP's tests, but for any other case, i think you should bet on the more-popular unit testing suite that can be used in every project ([PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/))

Happy testing :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm going to wait for another opinion, but this is the best in my opinion from now. I'm using CodeIgniter, not CakePHP, but I understood your point of view.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any test with codeignitor's build in unit test class. but it looks like that this class provide only very simple assertion function (maybe it is because of the pursuit of lightweight) and the worst thing is, you have to mess up the testing code with your production code.

For unit test, it offers much more assertion functions, more features: like code coverage, selenium RC...etc. so it can extend your ability to ensure code quality. one more benefit is, it does not depend on any of your framework code, so you can easily migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Unit Testing Class is quite simple test suite. If you need full unit testing of your code use [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/).

Answer (score -2):

Codeigniter has its own unit testing feature

Please go to http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/unit_testing.html

Thanks

Comment: I know it. In my main post I put this information, but what I need is a comparison between this class and other php unit tests like PHPUnit or Toast. Which is better and why.

Comment: Okey...
Now if you have good time for unit test in your project then definitely go for the PHPUnit.
I have good experience with that